# Did Novell Netware ever come in 64-bit?

Tags: novell

I need to know for my script, was there ever a 64-bit version of Netware? I am going to guess no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, I would be pretty sure.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novell_NetWare

NetWare 6.5 was released in August 2003 - last version that is, the next onwe was named Open Enterprise Server and a different product. It's version 2 has 64 bit as feature, so it is quite samfe to assume that Netware did not have it.

Answer (score 1):

64bit Netware did exist inside Novell as a project for some time around 1999/2000, and got to be pre-alpha stage code before the project was dropped. Novell has now ported most of the Netware services that were Netware centric over to Linux, and most of the Netware services are now available in OES2 which runs atop SLES (Suse Linux) which is available in 64bit.